# Selenium with python Unable to localize area text in IFRAME box

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, textarea

I m using Selenium with python and have been trying to click a text area, and modify a message Description. The text box's HTML looks like this:

[image]
I have an error when I try with this code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: browsingContext.currentWindowGlobal is null
```

My code:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")

#switch to selected iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "html/body/p")
element.clear()
element.sendkeys("new description")
```

try to do tests with Selenium on a web site

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The context may be still on another IFRAME which you have switched but forgotten to switch back to main/default context. So, switch to default context first before switching into this IFRAME, see the code below:

```
# Switch to main frame of the page first
driver.switch_to.default_content()
iframe = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")
#switch to selected iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

2. `element.sendkeys("new description")` -- This is incorrect

   Change it to below:

```
element.send_keys("new description")
```

Note: It's `send_keys` and not `sendkeys`

Comment: thank you for your reply
for send_keys it's good in my code.
I now have the error: Unable to locate element: /html/body/p;
how can we locate an element in a precise way.